# making preview of the image readonly/disabled

Tags: css

On my page I want particular image to be viewed `disable` / `readonly`. Not clickable

Codepan: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/GzLri)

```
<li><a href=""><img height="50" width="50" src="http://www.imge.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/imge_net-37.jpg"></a>
```

css:

```
img{
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

but it does not make any change.
any suggestion?

UPDATE:

What is your view for:

```
document.getElementbyId('idofimg').disabled = true
```

Comment: What do you mean by readonly?

Comment: Currently you have the <a> tag which makes the img clickable. If you delete that it will be unclickable.

Comment: @OriShuss: thanks, but anything without removing <a>? bcoz I need to repeatedly do this and removing anchor tag messes up the preview style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. If you want the image not clickable just use this simple css class

```
.avoid-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Edit: Usage

After defining css class to your stylesheet, just use below

```
<li><a href=""><img class="avoid-clicks" height="50" width="50" src="http://www.imge.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/imge_net-37.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: thanks, but how could I user this? I dont want all images to be disable

Comment: Ok but, you haven't add css to your stylesheet. please include .avoid-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
} to your css file

Answer (score 1):

If you remove your anchor tag it will be only view,

```
<li><a href=""><img height="50" width="50" src="http://www.imge.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/imge_net-37.jpg"></a>
```

replaced with this

```
<li><img height="50" width="50" src="http://www.imge.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/imge_net-37.jpg"></li>
```

Comment: thanks, but anything without removing `<a>`? bcoz I need to repeatedly do this and removing anchor tag messes up the preview style

Comment: Can you explain little more then what are you trying to accomplish and why it needs to be that way?

Comment: i want to show my design to someone else frequently. Few images which may change later those I want to show in `disabled` mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove `<a>` tag, Then you can do like this

**Change this**

```
<a href=""><img>...</a>
```

**to this**

```
<a><img>...</a>
```